# ASP.NET MVC - Reusable Control with Content

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. In my app, I have multiple layout files (~10). I have a block of HTML that is similar across the layout files. For that reason, I want to put it into a reusable control, because I anticipate some change will be needed to it.

On some of the pages that reference my layout files that use this control, I want to insert something into that a content area of the control. To demonstrate, imagine I have a layout file like this:

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@** MY REUSED BANNER CONTROL GOES HERE **@

<div class="container">
  @RenderBody()
</div>
```

**Banner.file** [not sure what to use]

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      Hello
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
       @RenderSection("bannerContent", required: false)      
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-3">
      Leave
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**MyPage.cshtml**

```
@{
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml"
}

<div>
  Main content goes here
</div>

@section bannerContent {
  <div>This goes into Banner.file</div>
}
```

The above code does not work. It is there to communicate the idea. From my understanding, a partial view won't work because partial's don't support sections. What are my options here?

Comment: If you need to pass data into a view partial, then pass it via a model.

Comment: @mason - I'm trying to do more than pass data in. I want to have a customized display for certain screens within the Banner.[file] area. I just provided a simple example. However, I really want to do something that is more stylized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I could understand you need something like this.

- Create _banner.cshtml in ~/Views/Shared.

  ```
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
          Hello
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3" id="banner_content"> // Here your page specific content will go

      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-3">
          Leave
      </div>
  </div>
  ```
- _LayOut.cshtml

  ```
  @Html.Partial("_banner"); // Reusable banner html
      <div class="container">
          @RenderBody()
      </div>
  ```
- MyPage.cshtml

  ```
  @{
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

  <div>
      Main content goes here
  </div>

  @section Scripts {
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#banner_conten').html('Your dynamic part.');
    });
  }
  ```

  I am not sure whether I understood your requirement completely or not. But check if it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I know I could do it with JavaScript. However, I'd really like to be able to do it server-side.

Comment: Do you want to use model binding for your _banner.cshtml ?